# When I point my browser to example.com/test.php, PHP from example.com/index.php is also being loaded

Tags: php, mysql

I have looked for an answer to why this is doing this and I can't seem to figure it out. I am trying to make a simple stat counter, on my `index.php` I have

```
$fromstr = 'index';
$country = 'TEST';
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "*****";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO counter (Country, IP, referrer)
VALUES ('$country', '$ip', '$fromstr')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$conn->close();
```

When I would visit `index.php`, it was adding the same entry into the database twice. I tried testing why it was happening so made an additional file `test.php`. I put almost the same code, just changing the `$fromstr` and leaving leaving the `$country` field blank. My code is:

```
$fromstr = 'test';
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "*****";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO counter (Country, IP, referrer)
VALUES ('$country', '$ip', '$fromstr')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$conn->close();
```

When I visit `test.php`, it correctly adds the entry with `Country->NULL IP->(ip address) referrer->"test"` however it ALSO adds the query that the `index.php` is supposed to add (`Country->"TEST" IP->(ip address) referrer->"index"`).

TL;DR: When I visit `index.php` my server executes the query to insert something into a database, however it (for some odd reason) does it twice. I made another file `test.php` to insert a different query and it inserts the correct query once then also the query on the index page, even though the index page is never visited. Why would it be doing this?

Comment: can you upload whole script to pastebin?

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file?

Comment: Is there any HTML in your code that's missing here, or are you just typing in the pages manually?

Comment: For the index page, there is additional HTML and PHP. This is why I made a test.php which ONLY contains the PHP listed above. I am typing the pages in manually.

Comment: It looks like there was an old .htaccess rewrite rule that was causing the problem. The URL didn't seem to meet the criteria to be re-written, I'm not sure why it was doing that however I have removed the .htaccess and it is working great. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If this is your actual source code you have a syntax error already. You forgot to add a single quote after the word `TEST` in following line:

```
$country = 'TEST;
```